# Enviar parâmetros ocultos para outra página, sem mostrá-los na URL

Tags: php, htaccess

Após fazer uma busca em um `form` method `POST`.

```
<form method="POST" action="../controller/precontBuscaProg.php">
  <input type="date" name="dataini">
</form>
```

Recebo em outra página o que foi enviado recebendo os dados assim:

```
$dataIni = $_POST['dataini'];
$dataFim = $_POST['datafim'];
$dstPost = $_POST['dst'];
$orgPost = $_POST['org'];
$stPost = $_POST['st'];

$objProg = new Prog();
$objProg->setdataoprini($dataIni);
$objProg->setdataoprfim($dataFim);
$objProg->setdest($dstPost);
$objProg->setorig($orgPost);
$objProg->setst1($stPost);

$params= '?'.http_build_query(array('dataini'=> $dataIni, 'datafim'=>$dataFim, 'dst'=> $dstPost, 'org'=> $orgPost, 'st'=> $stPost));
header('location: ../view/programacao.php'. $params);
```

Me retorna na url isto. Existe algum jeito de esconder isto na url ?

```
programacao.php?dataini=2016-08-16&datafim=2016-10-29&dst=%25%25&org=%25%25&st=1
```

E deixar somente isto ?

```
programacao.php
```

Se existe outro meio alem do .htaccess gostaria de saber.

Comment: Primeiro se ele  ta gerando isso, não esta fazendo post e sim get

Comment: Isso, obrigado irei editar a pergunta.

Comment: @Otto você precisa mudar o  method="get" para  method="post", na tag form, ou se não existir você adiciona  method="post". Também precisará mudar a forma que o php receberá esses dados

Comment: @FabianoCacinPinel no meu form está POST. Ai eu recebo eles assim `$dataIni = $_POST['dataini'];`. Após receber envio eles por um `header('location: ../view/programacao.php'. $params);` para outra página ficando assim como esta na pergunta. E recebo eles da ulr com um `$_GET`.

Comment: @FabianoCacinPinel se você prestar atenção a pergunta não é minha, então suponho que o comentário é para o dono da postagem

Comment: @Kevin.F get envia tudo pela url post não, siga a dica do Fabiano que ficará da forma que você quer

Comment: @otto, desculpa, era para o kevin.

Comment: @kevin dê uma pesquisada sobre redirecionamento via post então, aqui achei um exemplo não sei se funciona http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045097/php-redirect-and-send-data-via-post . Mas se o objetivo seja esconder as informações você pode tentar criptografalas e depois descriptografalas

Comment: @kevin uma outra forma de fazer armazena-las numa sessão e recupera-las depois

Answer (score -1):

Considerando que a finalidade é desconhecida e desconsiderando questões de SEO,

talvez, algo que resolve é armazenar numa variável de sessão.

Nesse trecho final, ao invés de construir uma URL, salve numa variável de sessão

```
$params= '?'.http_build_query(array('dataini'=> $dataIni, 'datafim'=>$dataFim, 'dst'=> $dstPost, 'org'=> $orgPost, 'st'=> $stPost));
header('location: ../view/programacao.php'. $params);
```

Ficaria assim

```
$_SESSION['search'] = array(
    'dataini' => $dataIni,
    'datafim' => $dataFim,
    'dst' => $dstPost,
    'org' => $orgPost,
    'st' => $stPost
);

header('location: ../view/programacao.php?search='. $token);
```

Na página `programacao.php`, verifique a existência da sessão de acordo com o parâmetro `search`.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['search'])) {
    $parametros_busca = $_SESSION['search'];
}
```

Eu omiti o [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) para simplificar a didática.

Exemplo básico de como usar variáveis de sessão:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12368588/1685571

obs: Algo confuso na sua pergunta é que o título aponta para uma direção e o contexto mostra outra. No final, interpretei que não tem nada a ver com URL rewrite. A menos que afirme o contrário com mais clareza.